# Including a Figure and its caption without including the plot (rmarkdown, knitr)

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

I am writing a paper using `rmarkdown`, `knitr`, and the [`rticles` package](https://github.com/rstudio/rticles). This paper will be submitted to [PLOS ONE](https://journals.plos.org/plosone/) and I am using the PLOS ONE LaTeX template available in the `rticles` R package.

PLOS ONE requires the Figure captions to appear in text (where the Figures are supposed to appear) whereas Figures are to be uploaded separately from the main manuscript.

Therefore, I am wondering whether there is a way of including figure captions in a PDF file generated using `knitr`, while not including the plots?

Below is presented a screenshot of the desired result. The LaTeX template is also available on [Overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/latex-template-for-plos-public-library-of-science-articles/tmfpqfxwdxbs).

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You could hide the plot (as originally suggested by @duckmayer) and add the caption with the help of the LaTeX package `caption`:

````
---
title: Title of submission to PLOS journal
author:
  - name: Alice Anonymous
    email: alice@example.com
    affiliation: Some Institute of Technology
    corresponding: alice@example.com
address:
  - code: Some Institute of Technology
    address: Department, Street, City, State, Zip
abstract: |
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.

author_summary: |
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.

output: rticles::plos_article
header-includes:
  - \usepackage{caption}
---

# Introduction

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.

```{r pressure, echo=FALSE,  fig.show='hide', results='asis', fig.path="plots-"}
plot(pressure)
cat("\n\\captionof{figure}{Here is a figure caption.}\n")
```
````

Result:

[image]

In this case the figure to submit would have name `plots-pressure-1.pdf`

Answer (score 1):

I would just shrink the plot in the final output to dimensions 0 x 0 using the chunk options `out.width` and `out.height`. (See this great documentation for all of the chunk options: https://yihui.name/knitr/options/#plots).

For example:

````
---
title: "SO Answer"
author: "duckmayr"
date: "9/24/2019"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

Here's how to make the figure with the caption but without the plot:

```{r pressure, fig.cap='Here is a figure caption.', out.width=0, out.height=0}
plot(pressure)
```
````

[image]

#### Update: Where are the plot files?

If you add a line such as

```
knitr::opts_chunk$set(fig.path = "figures/")
```

to the `setup` chunk above, the plots will be saved in the `figures/` subdirectory. For example, after knitting

````
---
title: "SO Answer"
author: "duckmayr"
date: "9/24/2019"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
knitr::opts_chunk$set(fig.path = "figures/")
```

Here's how to make the figure with the caption but without the plot:

```{r pressure, fig.cap='Here is a figure caption.', out.width=0, out.height=0}
plot(pressure)
```
````

I can see the files in `~/figures/`:

```
[duckmayr@duckmayr-pc ~]$ ls ~/figures/
pressure-1.png
```

(Since you're knitting to PDF, by default your plot images will also be saved as PDFs, not PNGs).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It also hides the caption though.

Comment: Thank you for the hack! I am also using it but I was wondering whether there is another (cleaner) way of doing it using knitr... More precisely and ideally, the plot would still be generated (so that it can be submitted separately from the manuscript) but it would not be included in the PDF.

Comment: @LadislasNalborczyk The plot is still generated, but depending on your settings may be deleted during the knitting process. Will add an update to address this issue soon.